# Consolidate Functions that receive a function parameter

Tags: c#, .net-core

I have got the below functions:

```
public static async Task<MyReturnType> MyFunction(Func<MyReturnType> func)
{
    // do stuff
    while (/* some conditions */)
    {
        var myReturn = func();
        // do stuff
    }
    // do stuff
}

public static async Task<MyReturnType> MyFunction(Func<Task<MyReturnType>> func)
{
    // do stuff
    while (/* some conditions */)
    {
        var myReturn = await func();
        // do stuff
    }
    // do stuff
}
```

As you can see, these 2 functions are identical except that the passed in function is called differently. Is there a way to consolidate these 2 functions into 1 so that I don't have to duplicate the other code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can delete the first overload entirely, and whenever you want to call the first overload, e.g.

```
await MyFunction(() => new MyReturnType());
```

You can use [`Task.FromResult`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.fromresult?view=net-5.0) to wrap the `MyReturnType` into a `Task<MyReturnTask>`:

```
await MyFunction(() => Task.FromResult(new MyReturnType()));
```

`FromResult` gives you a completed task, so `await func()` doesn't do any waiting, and evaluates gets the result synchronously, similar to what happens in the first overload.

Though I would prefer keeping the first overload, and having it call the second overload:

```
public static Task<MyReturnType> MyFunction(Func<MyReturnType> func)
    => MyFunction(() => Task.FromResult(func()))
```